# Does Enpass work on Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, password

I am new with Enpass and was searching for some Password manager which works on all 3 main OS's (Linux, Windows, OS X) and I found Envato.

Tested it on Windows and MAC and it works perfectly fine!

BUT, on Ubuntu it simply just doesn't work because the "Verify browsers" can't be ticked:

[image]

[image]

And on the [Official Website](https://www.enpass.io/blog/enpass-50-for-linux-extending-to-extensions/) it says this:

> Unlike MAC and Windows, Enpass in Linux doesn't verify the code signature of browsers. Code signature verification is a kind of authentication of web browsers if they are legitimate enough to share the passwords for autofill.
>
> While Windows and MAC operating systems support code signature verification, unfortunately in the case of Linux, it's not possible.
>
> This doesn't mean that you can't use extensions on Linux but we strongly recommend you download the web browsers from authentic sources i.e. Firefox and Chrome website or official repositories only to avoid any chance of security threat.

Is there a way to fix this problem? Or maybe someone could recommend some cross platform password manager that simply works?

Comment: lastpass might be a good option  ...

Comment: How does it work? Can you have the passwords offline not in the cloud? It wants me to make an account on their website.

Comment: It's a cloud based service... check keypass2, I guess it's cross platform however I don't know if it has a browser extension or not.

Comment: I have figured it out. The problem was that I downloaded Enpass from official website and that version didn't work. And later I found that you have to add a repository for ubuntu and then install with apt. And that version works just fine.

Comment: I will "NIKE" it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured this out now...

The problem was that I had installed Enpass from the official site and that is the reason why it didn't work...

I had to follow these steps:

```
sudo -i
echo "deb http://repo.sinew.in/ stable main" > \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/enpass.list

wget -O - https://dl.sinew.in/keys/enpass-linux.key | apt-key add -

apt update
apt install enpass
exit
```

And then install the browser extension and run the Enpass program

And it will work.